# Set easyadmin_autocomplete Select Null by default. Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I would like to know if there is any way to put `null` value by *default* in the *easyadmin_autocomplete select*.

The first item in the list is selected and filled with data from database but i need a `null` value by default and setted automaticly. The goal is a first result point to an empty one (Choose one...).

Do you know how to do it?

Can you think of any way combining the options defined below?

```
#easy_admin.yml
Product:
      class: App\Entity\Product
      controller: App\Controller\ProductController
      new:
        fields:
          - { property: 'category', label: 'Category', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Category' } }
 }
```

In this example, one select has a `placeholder` with the text 'Any' (Ninguno). I need to know why is handling them different.
[image: form_pic]
These are the options defined for the attr *fields -> type_options* of the `yml`:

1. action
2. allow_extra_fields
3. allow_file_upload
4. attr
5. auto_initialize
6. block_name
7. by_reference
8. class
9. compound
10. constraints
11. csrf_field_name
12. csrf_message
13. csrf_protection
14. csrf_token_id
15. csrf_token_manager
16. data
17. data_class
18. disabled
19. empty_data
20. error_bubbling
21. error_mapping
22. extra_fields_message
23. help
24. help_attr
25. inherit_data
26. invalid_message
27. invalid_message_parameters
28. label
29. label_attr
30. label_format
31. mapped
32. method
33. multiple
34. post_max_size_message
35. property_path
36. required
37. translation_domain
38. trim
39. upload_max_size_message
40. validation_groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If setting your default value would be a solution for you (like zero), service listener might be an answer:

```
// You need to add this listener yourself:
class ProductServiceListener
{
    ...

    // you can manipulate entity in this level as you wish:
    public function preUpdate(LifeCycleEventArgs $args)
    {

       // You will focus to Product entity, so block others:
       if (!(get_class($entity) == 'App\Entity\Product')) {
           return;
        }

        // Set whatever default value you want if it's null:
        if($entity->getCategory() == null) {
           $entity->setCategory(0); // Zero, as an example.
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Few years later in EasyAdmin 4 this problem still exists. If you like there is my custom JS fix which works globally

Your dashboard

```php
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return parent::configureAssets()
            ->addJsFile('custom.js');
    }
}
```

public/custom.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    let selectFields = document.querySelectorAll('.form-select');
    if (selectFields.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < selectFields.length; i++) {

            // if TomSelect exists and select field does not have truly selected option while element.selectedIndex not working here
            if (selectFields[i].tomselect && selectFields[i].querySelector('option[selected]') === null) {
                selectFields[i].tomselect.clear();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a placeholder like value for `easyadmin_autocomplete`.
The normal way for a choice type is to use the `placeholder` option as described in the [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder). But `easyadmin_autocomplete` does not extend that type and it is a standalone type. Can't you use a choice type or entity type with the placeholder option. The only need for the `easyadmin_autocomplete` type is if there are a lot of entities and it will slow the application if all are loaded on the page.

My best bet is that you can extend the `easyadmin_autocomplete`. Because the `easyadmin_autocomplete` uses `EntityType` you can add the option for placeholder in the `configureOptions` method in the extended type. That will delegate the option to the `EntityType` but even then it is not displayed in the html because of the `select2` javascript which also needs to be modified.

If it is a must I recommend the way to extend the type, add the option and also add custom javascript to easyadmin that will handle the new type and add the placeholder option. You can see the [select2 documentation](https://select2.org/placeholders) on how to set the placeholder.

But if you can use the entity or choice type for your select it is the preferred solution.